# Deploying GF4.0 in Solaris

Tags: unix, glassfish, solaris, glassfish-4

Im trying to install Glassfish 4.0 in a Solaris system, outside the users home folder.

I set up asenv.conf file and i can create the domain, but performing several different actions like restarting the domain  or enable secure admin I get the message:

"Unable to create client data directory:/export/home/appbill/.gfclient"
"NCLS-ADMIN-00010"

/export/home/appbill is the home folder of my user.. but I dont want any files to be created there..

GF is instaled at /opt/folder1/glassfish4/

I don't know if there na env variable I must set or what's exactly happening but this shouldn't be hard to solve..

Any ideas?

Comment: tried the $home env variable but it was not that

Comment: the `~/.gfclient` directory is required for a lot of user data, including the OSGi cache and some security stuff. I'm not sure of a way to change the location of it, so unless there's a very good reason to move it, it might be best to try and workaround the problem.

Comment: But how is GF defining that the value for that folder is the home folder of the user?